# Время остановки рекламной кампании

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Нужно задавать время выключения рекламной кампании, время в unixtime получаю так:

```
function stopTime(){
$h = date("H");
$min= date("i");
$other = date("d.m.Y");

  return strtotime($h.":".$min." ".$other);
}
```

Но видимо из-за задержки или других факторов получаю

```
Some ads error occured: Указанное время остановки уже прошло
```

Если увеличить текущее время+1 или +5 минут также не работает. Если увеличить +1 час - тогда все ок.

[Метод](https://vk.com/dev/ads.updateCampaigns)
Пояс сервера GMT+3 как и вк

Comment: А с часовыми поясами всё нормально?

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо за наводку - скорее всего нет, сейчас проверим.

Comment: Летнее время ещё?